# Wrong position of popover in scrollview iOS

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uipopover

I have a button that will show the popover. The popover must appear under the button. But it appears somewhere on the screen.

**Here's My Code for the popover**

```
UIView *popoverView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,340)]; 
[popoverView addSubview:tblViewMenu];
popoverContent.view = popoverView;
popoverContent .contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(620,620);
popPickerController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
[popPickerController presentPopoverFromRect:anchor.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUpanimated:YES];
```

BTW this popover will show inside a scrollview.

Comment: I'm just waiting for the accept delay but after that I'll accept an answer and it was iPatel who answers first but thanks for the info mate I've upvoted your answer too. :D

Comment: I have just reviewed your questions and suggested. Yes of-course you should accept iPatel's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following code for present popoverView.

```
[popover presentPopoverFromRect:button.frame inView:self.scrollView permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft | UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 3):

Give immediate parent of button as parameter value `inView:`

```
[popPickerController presentPopoverFromRect:anchor.frame
                                     inView:anchor.superview
                   permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                   animated:YES];
```

Always make sure to give right parent while presenting popover.

Answer (score 0):

[ur popovername presentPopoverFromRect:[(UIButton *)sender frame] inView:anchor.superview permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];